# Regressor-based L2 penalty

Tags: multiple-regression, regularization, overfitting

I'm working on a multiple regression problem where I have reasons to believe some (if not all) of the regressors have been cherry picked/data mined to a varying degree. My hypotheses are that there's a general regression to mean effect and also some time dependent data mining (i.e., a regressor that was coded long time ago when the research standard wasn't as robust will see greater decay). Given this context, is it possible to use L2 penalties that are different for each regressor? Would this even make sense?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78744/different-regularization-parameter-per-parameter. Does that answer your Q?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks